# How to Get Folder Shortcuts/Links to Work When Copying Template Folder Contents to New Folder

Tags: file-transfer, symbolic-link, folder-redirection, file-shortcut, files-folders

I have a lot of 'template' folders, the contents which I use to copy into new folders that I create.  My problem is getting shortcuts within the copied folders to point back to object the folder that is now copied to the new folder.
For a simplistic Example:

"Template Folder" - folder structure as follows:

1. Folder A
     a) File/shortcut to folder B
2. Folder B

"New Folder" (with contents of "template folder" copied into it)  - folder structure as follows:

1. Folder A
     a) File/shortcut to folder B
2. Folder B

Problem is, when I click on file (now located within "new folder") with shortcut to folder B, Windows then takes me back to folder B in the ORIGINAL template folder, not Folder B in the "new folder".

Is there a way I can set up the file shortcut to folder B (within the "template folder", that once copied into a new folder (along with other "template folder" files and folders) would direct Windows to then open "folder B" within the newly created folder, versus the original "template folder"?

I have tried doing some research into "symbolic links" - but don't quite understand if this is what is needed to accomplish my goals.  Thanks. -Cfguy100

Comment: Windows shortcuts don't support relative paths, which is what you're asking for here. What you need to do is create the shortcut files when laying down a new set of template folders. This can be done with a script.